# Different time format between browsers

Tags: c#, string-formatting, datetime-format

I have a template label in my GridView:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
 Text='<%# String.Format("{0:t}", Eval("Time_From")) %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

But when my Gridview binds, it shows 1:00 PM in Mozilla but 13:00 in IE.

Why is this happening?

Comment: [This](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101508-1.aspx) might help explain the discrepancy.

Comment: I'll go to finding out if this is a server side or client side behavior (javascript based on browser type) as first step

Comment: @M.Babcock how are different data types in the db going to cause different browsers to render differently?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like formatting picks different cultures, but I don't believe default ASP.Net site modifies "current culture" based on culture in incoming request... Maybe some of your other code changes current culture based on something?

Try to show [Thread.CurrentThread.CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) to see if server side culture is different.